Auto Import Contact Form Submissions into CRM
We have developed a CRM using asp.net and I want to have the ability to allow users to automatically import their contact form submissions from their website into the CRM as a new entry. What is the best way to do this? Currently use SendGrid for our email system.
Looking for suggestions, thought SendGrid might have something that could help.
